# What are the keyboard shortcuts on Mac OS for blender?

Tags: shortcut

What are the keyboard shortcuts on Mac OS for blender?

an answer was given, but it was not correct. Anyone have the correct answer?

The answer that was given was go to FILE > PREFERENCES... however, there is no "preferences" under "file". [image]

Comment: The same as in every other platform. Why you ask?

Comment: Oh okay, can I assign them myself? If so how can I do so? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Keyboard shortcuts can be found and edited in menu **File** -> **User Preferences** -> **Input** tab:

**Update** For Bender v2.93.1 2021-06-23 on macOS:
**Edit** -> **Preferences** -> **Input** tab:

[image]

**PS**. don't forget to press **Save User Settings**, after making changes here.

Comment: But be careful - when you save your user settings, Blender will open from then on exactly how it was in that state. If you changed the window arrangement, messed with the theme colors, or had a half-finished project open, Blender will use that exact setup as your startup file.

Comment: @X-27 you aren't right, you are confusing with another command  **Save startup file** (Ctrl + U). This button saves only settings

Comment: @Mark Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//blender.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Blender way of saying thank you.

Comment: @Mark Better yet, if this answer satisfactorily answered your question, you can mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking the green check under the vote buttons.