# How to render my animation

Tags: animation

Can someone please help me render an animation? I'm facing trouble and I'm completely new to this..

LINK to the File : https://www.mediafire.com/file/74y5js2cnke6ha9/Cinematic_Movie_Text_Animation.blend/file

Comment: What have you tried, what did you research, what has failed?

Comment: [Render Menu](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/topbar.html#topbar-render) and [Output Settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/settings.html)

Comment: Can you please tell what you are having trouble with?

Comment: This forum is to answer specific questions, not generalised wishes. Please don't include emails etc as all communication should be through the here.

Comment: You should not add any personal information like your email and description should be clear and also the question should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

To render an animation.

1st press <kbd>0</kbd>/<kbd>Ins</kbd> key to go to camera. But here we can see that camera is not capturing the text, we need to adjust that first.

[image]

This view you are seeing without camera is perfect to set the camera. 
[image]

Now to set the camera to the view you are seeing, HIT <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+0</kbd>
[image]

Select the type output of animation like Image Sequence, ffmpeg(video) etc., and also set a location for storing tmp.

[image]

Now, play with the settings like renderengine, sampling etc., and then hit Render>Render Animation (or) <kbd>F12</kbd> to render animation. 
[image]

Wait for the animation to render.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Can you help with mac commands?

Comment: I'm not a macbook user but here : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105052/what-are-the-keyboard-shortcuts-on-mac-os-for-blender hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you so much